# Update query timing out after 10 seconds despite successfully submitting in React app

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Schema:

```
const SubmitDebtSchema = new Schema ({
  balance: [{
    balanceDate: Date,
    newBalance: Number
  }]
});
```

And I have the following function which appends new objects into the array:

```
  module.exports = async (req, res) => {

    let newDateObject = {
      balanceDate: req.body.balanceDate,
      newBalance: req.body.newBalance
    };

    await SubmitDebt.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.query.id },
      { $push: { balance: newDateObject } },
      {new: true, useFindAndModify: false}
    );

  };
```

However, despite the database successfully updating, it times out after 10 seconds with the following error message:

> 2020-11-23T16:51:57.138Z 25fa69c2-91a1-4a74-8034-af132d4d8eb3 Task
> timed out after 10.01 seconds

Does anyone have any feedback for how to resolve this? It also doesn't push to my 'dashboard' upon successful submission.

Here's my Axios front-end call:

onSubmit = async (e) => {

```
      e.preventDefault();

      let newBalanceDate = new Date();

      this.calculateUpdatedBalance()

      await axios.post("/api/edit/editDebtBalance",
      {
          balanceDate: newBalanceDate,
          newBalance: this.calculateUpdatedBalance(),
    },
    {
      params: {
        id: this.props.match.params.id
      }
    }
  )

      this.props.history.push('/dashboard');
    }
```

EDIT: My full serverless function file:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const SubmitDebt = require("../submit/submitDebtSchema");

require("dotenv").config();

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI);


  module.exports = async (req, res) => {

    let newDateObject = {
      balanceDate: req.body.balanceDate,
      newBalance: req.body.newBalance
    };

    return await SubmitDebt.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.query.id },
      { $push: { balance: newDateObject } },
      {new: true, useFindAndModify: false}
    );

  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you try returning the value?
A lambda function stops only when you return something, try this.

```
return await SubmitDebt.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.query.id },
      { $push: { balance: newDateObject } },
      {new: true, useFindAndModify: false}
    );
```

Notice that I only added return before the await statement, that's it.

Edit: Ahh.... I think this should work

```
let response = await SubmitDebt.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: req.query.id },
      { $push: { balance: newDateObject } },
      {new: true, useFindAndModify: false}
    );
return res.send(response)
```

since you're using an express app. I'm sorry I overlooked it previously.

Comment: Just tried this, not working unfortunately! It's still timing out. I think it needs a callback in there but not sure how to build it in.

Comment: I've added it now - fairly certain it won't be helpful though.

Comment: BTW, which node version are you using ?

Comment: It's v12.16.3 I believe

Comment: Well then you definitely don't need a callback, this should've worked, maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Works perfectly (again) - thank you so much for your help today... You’ve answered several of my questions!